# mySQL move records that contain a "," to new column

Tags: mysql

I'm wondering how I would write a query to take records from a single column and push them over to a new column. The records I'd like moved over all contain a single comma somewhere in the record. As an example:

Before:

```
Column1  
1. Smith, John  
2. Sue, Maggie  
3. Big Name Corp
```

After:

```
Column1  
1.  
2.  
3. Big Name Corp  

Column2  
1. Smith, John  
2. Sue, Maggie  
3.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE `tbl` SET `col2` = `col1` WHERE `col1` LIKE "%,%"

UPDATE `tbl` SET `col1` = "" WHERE `col1` LIKE "%,%"
```

i think it'll also work in a single query

```
UPDATE `tbl` SET `col2` = `col1`, `col1` = "" WHERE `col1` LIKE "%,%"
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I'll be giving this a go when I get back in